# Use actual MySQL on Raspbian Stretch instead of MariaDB

Tags: raspbian-stretch, debian, mysql, mariadb

I have a web based project which I wrote with NodeJS. I moved the project to my Raspberry Pi which runs on Raspbian Stretch. The project has a lot of lines of code which deal with MySQL connections. However, when I installed MySQL on Stretch, I got MariaDB. It is not possible for me to convert every line of MySQl related code to use MariaDB. Due to that, I need MySQL as it used to get installed on previous Debian versions (like Jesse).

How do I install MySQL instead of MariaDB ? On a few forums I read that I need to build it from the source code. Is there another way? And if not, then can someone guide me on building it from the source code?

Answer (score 4):

MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL and should be mostly compatible to it.
Unless you need a very specific feature of MySQL, MariaDB should work just fine.

For more details about the compatibility of MySQL and MariaDB see the following two links:

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226334/node-mysql-with-mariadb

If you really need MySQL, they provide an apt repository for mysql binaries.
Here is a short summary of the necessary steps:

- Add repository via install package or manually
- Install and configure mysql as needed

For more information see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/